# Test with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js

I use chai module to test code.

```
var CONFIG = require('./config');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();
var server = CONFIG.apiPath;

chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe('TEST', function() {
  it('getAllLandingPage completed',function(){
    chai.request(server)
      .get('getAllLandingPage')
      .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(200);
        console.log('res: ', res) // not show
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

I want console.log(res) to show result so I can to know function right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss `done` in the callback function of `it`, try it as below

```
  it('getAllLandingPage completed',function(done){
    chai.request(server)
      .get('getAllLandingPage')
      .end(function(err, res){
        if (err)
           done(err);
        else {
           res.should.have.status(200);
           console.log(res) 
           done();
        }
      });
  });
```